# shopify/wordpress to Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, mobile, shopify

I was wondering if there are any tools to create mobile apps that's off WordPress /shopify so that customers can use the app to purchase goods. Does WordPress or shopify provide this service? I know that WordPress has an app. But uses need to navigate to the blog. What I need is a standalone mobile application. Thanks. If there isn't, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a standalone native app that lets your customers shop.
Check out Apptuse.com, they support Shopify +5 other platforms and seem to do exactly what you are looking for.